# How do you round a string in Python?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and a student, my college has chosen the worst book on earth for our course.  I cannot find examples of any concepts, so I apologize in advance as I know these concepts are very basic.  I hope you can help me.

I need to know how to use the round feature in a string.  I find examples but they do not show the string, just simple numbers.

Here is what we are supposed to get as an output:
Enter the gross income: 12345.67
Enter the number of dependents: 1

The income tax is $-130.87  <---- this is what we are supposed to figure out

Here is the coding we are given to alter:

```
TAX_RATE = 0.20
STANDARD_DEDUCTION = 10000.0
DEPENDENT_DEDUCTION = 3000.0

# Request the inputs
grossIncome = float(input("Enter the gross income: "))
numDependents = int(input("Enter the number of dependents: "))   

# Compute the income tax
taxableIncome = grossIncome - STANDARD_DEDUCTION - \
                DEPENDENT_DEDUCTION * numDependents
incomeTax = taxableIncome * TAX_RATE 

# Display the income tax

print("The income tax is $" + str(incomeTax))
```

As I do not have an NUMBER to plug into the formula - I have to figure out how to use "incomeTax" - I have no idea how to do this.  THe book doesnt explain it.  Help?

Comment: `incomeTax` holds a (float) number. What you want is to `format()` it as string. Look up `format()` in the Python docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `round` just before making it a string:

```
print("The income tax is $" + str(round(incomeTax,2)))
```

Output:

```
Enter the gross income: 12345.67
Enter the number of dependents: 1
The income tax is $-130.87
```

Comment: This has the possibility of only showing one decimal place if `incomeTax` rounds to a tenth.

Comment: You rock!!!! That worked.  It was also simple, imagine if I had been given an example to use!  I do have a question for you:  I notice that I am having a lot of trouble finding examples for concepts.  I am googling with no results - am I using incorrect search terms?  How can I get the examples I am searching for without having to post in here constantly?

Comment: @queenv Happy to help, don't forget to accept after timer is up, i actually think that you didn't understand the point, you were planning to round a string, but actually you can round it before it becomes a string, so searching "round a decimal python" would be it.

Comment: @queenv Lol, just saw it too.

Answer (score 6):

You can use format strings:

```
print("The income tax is ${:.2f}".format(incomeTax))
```

If you are using Python 3.6+, you can also use f-strings:

```
print(f"The income tax is ${incomeTax:.2f}")
```

Comment: Thank you - I am just starting out I have no clue what an F string is and I doubt this book will explain.... :(

Comment: @queenv [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) describes the implementation, and [Python 3's f-Strings: An Improved String Formatting Syntax (Guide)](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) is a more approachable guide.

Comment: thank you I will add it to the list of alternate books :)

Comment: Short reminder that the dollar sign is part of the string and has nothing to do with the formatting. `{incomeTax:.2f}` is sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

Im a student as well, with the same dumb book and HW.

I tried the above

`str(round(incomeTax,2))`

and it didn’t work. Maybe I typed something wrong. After playing around I found this to work

```
 # Display the income tax

incomeTax = round(incomeTax,2)

print(“The income tax is $” + str(incomeTax))
```

I hope this helps some other poor soul searching the web for an answer!

Comment: Kindly format your question according to the rules. Please use control+K to write your code.